# How to invoke less with a pattern

Tags: less

I'm trying to combine `less +F` with a `&pattern`, but can't get it to work like I want:

```
less +F'&foo|bar' file.log
```

It seems to ignore my pattern.

Comment: If your looking for a regex, why not use `tail -f file.log | grep '&foo|bar'`

Comment: Because I want to be able to switch between tailing and browsing the file.

Comment: While I'm not sure what `+F` would do (what flavour of `less` is this?), the versions of `less` I have expect any search pattern via the `-p pattern` flag.

Comment: @thrig The +F enables scrolling in less..

Comment: @thrig What ryekayo said and while in less, you can activate scrolling with Shift-F and then use ^C to return to normal mode.

Comment: @thrig less +F -p'&foo|bar' does not work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the filter command before the follow command, otherwise the filter command is never applied (pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get out of follow mode cancels any pending input, including fake input injected via the command line).

So in the `+` argument, you need to pass the `&foo|bar` command first, then the `F` command. To terminate the `&` command, you need a newline.

```
less +$'&foo|bar\nF' file.log
```

(Assuming your shell is ksh, bash or zsh, where `$'\n'` expands to a newline.)